# Confirmation button on save button like delete already has

Tags: javascript, django, django-admin, action, admin

I want to modify Django admin interface.

There is delete button already has a confirmation page. But I want to add this confirmation to save or change buttons. Actually not exactly the same delete button.

I want to change default admin buttons like this JS or I want to add JS to admin buttons.

```
<input type="submit" onclick="linkSubmit('http://www.google.com')" value="Submit">
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function linkSubmit(link) {
  let text = "Press a button!\nEither OK or Cancel.";
  if (confirm(text) == true) {
    window.location.href = link;
  } else {
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
</script>
```

Comment: So you want an existing button to work exactly the same as it did before except if they click the button and then click cancel on your custom confirmation?

Comment: Yes, I want and confirmation step for save or change process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the solution in the files of the delete command. We took copies of the files confirm to the delete function and connected them to the confirm button.

We still can't give it as a alert. Gives confirmation on a another page.

Comment: Did you try my answer? It does exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: I tried but didnt work. I dont understand why. Thanks for answer

Comment: Can you share your project structure and where you put the template? Or create a repro project on GitHub. It is as simple as it looks and works well.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is already some type of event listener for the button I would add my own custom function as an additional listener for the on click event. Then I would put in my if(confirm) logic and call event.stopImmediatePropagation() as needed to prevent the original functionality from occuring.

Comment: How can I use that? I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create templates/admin/change_form.html in your project:

```html
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}

{% block admin_change_form_document_ready %}{{ block.super }}
<script id="django-admin-form-change-constants"
        data-model-name="{{ opts.model_name }}">
    let modelName = document.getElementById('django-admin-form-change-constants').dataset.modelName;
    let form = document.getElementById(modelName + '_form');
    form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
        let text = "Press a button!\nEither OK or Cancel.";
        if (!confirm(text)) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

2. Set `DIRS` in myproject/settings.py to point to your project's `templates` directory:

```py
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        ...
    }
]
```

References:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/overriding-templates/#overriding-from-the-project-s-templates-directory
- https://github.com/django/django/blob/4.1/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_form.html#L66-L74
- https://github.com/django/django/blob/4.1/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/change_form.js#L5